# How to install Selenium for python on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, selenium, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, headless

Hello I found serveral different options to download and install Selenium on my Raspberry pi, but none of them worked for me with the latest versions.

Could someone please tell me what I need and maybe which versions work together?
If its possible I want to run it headless.

Thanks for reading!

I'm running the newest raspbian jessie btw.

Comment: can you show what you have done, please?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question as you but couldn't find any answers, so I posted my own. Unlike you, I got a reply.

[Installing Selenium on Raspberry Pi on Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139340/installing-selenium-on-raspberry-pi-on-python)

If you want to see, just click the link.

I hope it helps!