# Installing Selenium on Raspberry Pi on Python

Tags: python, linux, selenium, raspberry-pi3

I have a new Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. I am using the latest version of Raspbian.

I have been trying to set up Selenium on Python but have failed.
There is little/no guidance on how to achieve this on the Pi.

I tried installing Selenium via pip, which worked but when I ran the following, I got an error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

This is the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' 
executable needs to be in PATH.
```

There seem to be solutions to this on other stackoverflow pages but none have solved my problem so far.

Could anyone give me any guidance as to how they have done it?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi! How is going?

Comment: In Raspberry pi, there is no firefox browser available. You will need to use chromium driver